# launchd not launching nginx on boot

Tags: macos, nginx, launchd

I have set up launchd to deal with nginx.

Everything was working before el capitan.

I have the file  file as `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
                       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key><string>nginx</string>
    <key>Program</key><string>/usr/local/bin/nginx</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key><true/>
    <key>NetworkState</key><true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key><string>/var/log/system.log</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key><true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

`launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist` returns `ok` but `nginx` stays disabled.

when I do `sudo launchctl list`, `ngin`x does not appear on the list.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but at the moment I'm completely lost.

Comment: This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything was working before el capitan.
>   I have the file file as /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist

El Capitan introduced [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (SIP).

> designed to help prevent potentially malicious software from modifying protected files and folders on your Mac

Files and folders that reside under `/System/Library/` and various other paths are reserved for Apple, such as:

```
• /bin
• /sbin
• /usr
• /System
```

Your daemon's plist should now reside in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.